# Anchor animate div based on offset of element

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to do is create a list of anchors that will animate a div full of images based on the offset of that image.

- ## a-one should animate ul#gallery

  based on the offset of #img-one.box.
- ## a-two should animate the ul#gallery

  based on the offset of #img-two.box.

So if ul#gallery is left: 0 and #img-two.box is at 300px. Then when you click #a-one, it will offset ul#gallery left: -300px to make #img-two.box essentially flush left.

I started an example but couldn't finish it here: http://jsfiddle.net/XmB2Y/1/

I will be more than happy to explain in more detail if confusing.

***Edit:***
Now that I am thinking about it. One way that I think it could be done is if you were to have the href of each link to be the same id as that corresponding box. Then what you could do is when a user clicks the link, look for the matching div and then calculate the offset. Then animate that ul#gallery the offest.left amount.

***Edit Two:***
So since the amount of links and the amount of images would always be the same.. could you use the `:nth-child` selector to correspond each link with each image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly you may try this http://jsfiddle.net/kpkM2/26/.

Comment: Hey this looks pretty good. However does it allow for boxes of different sizes? It looks like the width "105" is hard coded.. Can this somehow be a variable?

Comment: I may have to polish the code but now it's working with variable box size. See http://jsfiddle.net/kpkM2/56/